# Power button missing from Windows 10 Control-Alt-Delete and login screens

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

I am configuring a Windows 10 LTSC v1809 Enterprise image for commercial use and have a requirement to allow Shutdown via the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` screen.

- The power button is accessible from the Start Menu, but the Start Menu is not always going to be available to the user

I have checked all settings found via Google, however the power button is still not there:

- Local Security Policy [*Enabled*]: 
   `Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on`
- Group Policy *Start Menu and Taskbar* [*Not Configured*]: 
   `Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands`

  - Configured under both *Computer Configuration* and *User Configuration* and forcing them to *Disabled* does not make a difference
- Set the following Registry keys to `1`:

  ```
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\shutdownwithoutlog
  ```

  ```
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher_ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen
  ```

Is there any other setting I should check?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 Enterprise are you using exactly?  You can [edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Just to be sure open Regedit again `Win+R` and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell` > create a new key > DWORD (32 bit) Value  > "Launcher_ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen" > value to "1". Then reboot Windows

Answer (score 0):

The culprit ended up being the [`BrandingNeutral`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-embeddedlogon-brandingneutral) Registry value.